# ListView Images showed only when visible

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-listview, universal-image-loader

I have a `ListView` that loads images to the `ImageView` asynchronously. To achieve this i am using [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

But i would like to start loading this images only when they are visible in the listview. For example if the visible items of the listview are from 5 to 9, only those should be loaded. Also if the user scrolls very fast the `ListView` only when stopped those items should be loaded. 
What is the best way to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use "view reusing" in your listview adapter then you shouldn't do anything. UIL do it for you. UIL won't load ALL scrolled images, only those which are got in task pool (you can set set pool size in configuration). If you use "view reusing" then images which were scrolled fast won't be loaded. 
Look into example project on GitHub.

**UPD:** Since 1.7.0 version UIL have **`PauseOnScrollListener`**.

```
boolean pauseOnScroll = true;
boolean pauseOnFling = true;
listView.setOnScrollListener(new PauseOnScrollListener(pauseOnScroll, pauseOnFling));
```

Comment: Yes i am using "view reusing" with a ViewHolder. So if i use "view reusing" and do fast scroll those images don't be loaded, right? Just one more question, since the `ImageLoader.displayImage` is in the `getView` and this is called more than once will `ImageLoader` try to download the image again despite already having downloaded?

Comment: Right. When you use view reusing then previous loading task for view is canceled when view is reused. If you call displayImage() twice and simultaneously with the same imageUri then second task will wait until first task loads and caches image. When first task had loaded and displayed the image then second task continue his work and display image. So one image won't be loaded twice from network.

Comment: PauseOnScrollListener used only when "not reusing views in listview " right ?

Comment: No, you can use PauseOnScrollListener in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Use an [OnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html), the `onScrollStateChanged()` method is called when the ListView switches between `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE`, `SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL` (slower scrolling), and `SCROLL_STATE_FLING` (faster scrolling). With this you can choose to load new images only when the states is "Idle" or "Touch".

---

**Addition**

> In the first run the visible items of the ListView aren't shown. For example when the app starts if the ListView has 4 items visible those 4 images should be loaded.

I haven't used the Universal Image Loader myself, but from what you described below you need to know *how many* rows will be displayed before you start downloading. Try this:

- Write a Runnable to start the asynchronous downloads.
- Use your ListView's built-in Handler to call the Runnable *after* the rows have been drawn

For example:

```
private Runnable loadImages = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Start the asynchronous downloads
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    mListView.post(loadImages);
}
```

The `loadImages` will be called *after* the ListView is drawn so you will know exactly how many rows are visible.

Comment: I have tried to do that. In the `onScrollStateChanged` when the state was `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` i was finding the FirstVisiblePosition and the visible childs and then looping to display the images. The problem appeared when i first runned the App. Since i removed the loading of the images from the `getView` of the List Adapter, in the first run the visible items of the ListView aren't shown.

Comment: So you need to force the images to load _before_ the user scrolls the ListView?

Comment: Yes. For example when the app starts if the ListView has 4 items visible those 4 images should be loaded.

Comment: Ok, how do you start the asynchronous downloads? And why can't you start downloading in `onCreate()`?

Comment: I have the asynchronous downloads in the `onScrollStateChanged` . To start `onCreate` the downloads i would have first to see what items are visible and then loop the listview rows and start the download correct? And in the Adapter i would only set the items text of row correct?

Comment: Thanks, the "addition" seems to be a good solution. But since i am using UIL and @NOSTRA said won't load ALL scrolled images even those that were scrolled fast i will leave the default behaviour of UIL.